# query.filter and gql

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I am trying this function, however something is wrong. I stored the name "John" but when i pass the john to `username_` and call the `check_user` the output is always `return results`, even if the name is not stored in google data store. Why?

```
def check_user(self, username_):
    query = db.Query(Registrations)
    results = query.filter('username =', username_)
    if results:
        return results

user_username = self.request.get('username')
check_username_valid = self.check_user(user_username)

 if not check_username_valid:
    error_username_exists="Username already exists"
```

In the case of GQL, how can i pass the variable `username_` into the query? like:

```
 qr = db.GqlQuery("Select * from Registrations Where username = ?????")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

results is the query object not the result, you need to call `query.filter('username =', username_).get()` to return a single result or `query.filter('username =', username_).fetch()` to return all of them.

Comment: thanks, and just for learning, how pass the variable into to the query? This may cause some type of injection?

Comment: I think its just a simple string building, in ndb it get a lot more interesting.

Comment: No! Do not insert arguments using string concatenation! Use parameter substitution (":1", ":2", etc) as documented in the GQL docs.

Comment: @loops I didn't understand your question, I thought you asked how your variable is passed into the query in the code internally. Don't use string building for building GQL as it is sensitive to injection just like SQL.